# how to add the value written inside checkbox by user?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I wrote this code for add and remove Textboxes using AngularJS, but I want to add the value of checkbox which will written by user and display it on same page so what can I do it?

The code below will display 1 textbox and 3 buttons, if I click on append then it will add one more text box on page and when I click on remove then it will remove last checkbox.

And I want to add functionality for example if I append 4 checkboxes, and every checkbox I insert some values as number, then I click on add button then it will return the addition of values which I inserted before and return it on same page. so what should i write in code

```js
var app = angular.module('abc', []);
  app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.array=[1];
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="abc" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

  <body>
    <div ng-repeat="a in array">
      Textbox {{a}} <input type="text" id="{{a}}">
    </div>
    <button ng-click="array.push(array.length+1)">Append</button> 
    <button ng-click="array.pop(array.length-1)">Remove</button> 
    <button>Add</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `calcSum` function in the scope, which calculates the sum of the entered values and stores the sum in the scope. Then you can call that function with `ng-click`.

Note that I changed your array to directly contain the values entered in the textbox. This way you can directly calculate the sum of the array without having to loop through the inputs manually.

```js
var app = angular.module('abc', []);
  app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.array=[0];
  $scope.calcSum = function() {
     $scope.sum = $scope.array.reduce(function(total, num) {
        return total + num;            
     })
  }
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="abc" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

  <body>
    <div ng-repeat="a in array track by $index">
      Textbox {{$index}} <input type="number" ng-model="array[$index]">
    </div>
    <button ng-click="array.push(0)">Append</button> 
    <button ng-click="array.pop(array.length-1)">Remove</button> 
    <button ng-click="calcSum()">Add</button>
    <div>{{sum}}</div>
  </body>
</html>
```